# remove blank space in rdlc after rectangle hide

Tags: whitespace, rdlc, removing-whitespace

I'm working with rdlc report. 
My report looks like this:

[image]

Red color - title, blue and green - rectangles with tables inside.

I need to hide blue rectangle. But after rectangle hide, the report looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove that blank space between the title and green rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Rectangles` and put your `Label` and your two `Tablix` in a main `Tablix` with 5 header rows.

Then using `Advanced Mode` set `Hidden` property of row 3 (blue `Tablix`) and 4 (space between blue `Tablix` and green `Tablix`) according to your needs.

[image: Tablix]